# jQuery animated header on hover

Tags: jquery, header, hover, animated

I have found here useful piece of code. I really hope that someone can help me.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            },600);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'100px'
            },600);
        }  
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/76/

**Question:** How to do the same thing only on hover (not scroll)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you might think.

```
(1) $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
```

In regards to (1), the exact snippet of code you pasted is really just adding a data-attribute which I am guessing you don't need as you found the code online.

```
(2) $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
```

In regards to (2), .stop() just stops the animate abruptly without allowing it to finish

The key is to target the event of the mouse entering the div shown below:

```
$("#header_nav").mouseenter(function(){
```

and then again when it leaves to give you the mouseover effect shown below:

```
$("#header_nav").mouseleave(function(){
```

I've stripped the code to make it as simple as possible for you to read (DEMO below)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/311/)

It's pretty self explanatory, on mouseenter/mouseleave 'animate' (gradually reduce/increase) the height of the container.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is useful but revealed another problem. If you move quickly over the area, it still responds (it is annoying). It is better than the result would be something like this: http://coffeesurfing.illy.com/ How to do this? Sorry for my english.

Comment: On coffeesurfing.illy you will see if you scroll past quickly it moves slightly. I think they are using .stop() like this http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/318/

Comment: Almost close. Thank you. I'm not sure if you understand me correctly now, but is it possible to set the stop time (the time when the area is not responding if you hover on it)? Currently, it still responds.

Comment: Yes. You would need to make another question for me to code that. But basically have a timer that resets on mouseover and finishes on mouseleave.

Comment: I've already got the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872316/how-to-set-the-stop-time-on-hover