# How to set the stop time on hover?

Tags: jquery, time

Here is the code that I want to change:

```
$("#header_nav").mouseenter(function(){
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'50px'
            },600); 
});


$("#header_nav").mouseleave(function(){
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'100px'
            },600);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/318/

**Question:** How to set the stop time (the time when the area is not responding if you hover on it)?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop time"? Do you mean that you don't want the animation to begin until after the mouse has hovered over the element for at least x seconds?

Comment: What do you mean by 'set the stop time'? `stop()` is used to pause the current animation on the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "stop time", but I would guess that you mean that you don't want the animation to begin until after the mouse has hovered over the element for at least some minimum amount of time, say 500ms. If so then you can use the [`.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), and call [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) with the `true` argument to clear any animations in the queue:

```
$("#header_nav").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).stop(true).delay(500).animate({
            height:'50px'
        },600); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
});
```

Updated version of demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/321/

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I need. There are still good people. :) Thank you very much. The idea is that it should not respond when I hover on it quickly.